# How to pull entries with Date Created > start and < end?

Tags: plugin-development, search, elementcriteriamodel

I'm building an export plugin in Craft 2 and the entries are saved by the front-end and are never enabled, so no Post Date.  I have a form with the forms.date selectors that sends a start and end date to my controller.  How can I filter on Date Created?  After and before only works on Post Date.

I have this for now:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'contestEntries';
// Date Created >= start_date
// Date Created <= end_date
$criteria->status = null;
$entries = $criteria->find();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is syntax you can use to search a date field between two dates.

```
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($settings["start_date"]["date"]));
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($settings["end_date"]["date"]));

$criteria->dateCreated = ['and','>= '.$startDate, '<= '.$endDate];
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this works at all for what I'm asking.  You could use this if the entries would have a start_date and an end_date field, but not for what I'm asking.  I want to do this, but against the Date Created field, using a user input for the start and end date, pulling entries that are created between those 2 dates.

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, it's almost what I ended up with, using your first example.  Thanks for that.  But just so you know, you can't use the DateTime object in this case, trying to concatenate it with a string.  Just use         
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($settings["start_date"]["date"]));
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($settings["end_date"]["date"]));

If you can update your answer to reflect this, it will be perfect.

Thanks for the help